Ffmpeg - Generate loudnorm conversion log file
I have a bat file that reads several audio files in the "µudios LUFS" folder and performs LUFS normalization by copying the files to the "Normalized µudios Lufs" folder.
I'm trying to generate the log of each file, with its respective name, in another folder called Logs.
On the command line where the files will be normalized, I use -report:
-report file="%Userprofile%\Desktop\Logs\!filename!.mp3.log":level=24
Code:
md "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs"    ------> temp folder audio files being normalized   
pushd "%Userprofile%\Desktop\µudios LUFS"                 ------> folder with the original audio files

                                                                                                      __
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('where .:*.mp3 ^|findstr /vi "_LOUDNORM  _EBU"') DO (                          |                
  SET "filename=%%~na"                                                                                  |
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%%a" -af "[0:a]loudnorm=print_format=summary" -f null NUL 2> "%%~na.log"      |   
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input Integrated" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET II=%%b)               |
  @FOR /F "tokens=4" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input True Peak" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET ITP=%%b)               |  set original audio files values  
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input LRA" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET ILRA=%%b)                    |  to use as parameters in loudnorm
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Input Threshold" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET IT=%%b)                |
  @FOR /F "tokens=3" %%b IN ('FINDSTR /C:"Target Offset" "%%~na.log"') DO (SET TO=%%b)                  |
  DEL "%%~na.log"                                                                                     __|

  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%b IN ('ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a -show_entries "stream=bit_rate,sample_rate" -of "csv=p=0" "!filename!.mp3"')     ----> getting the sample rate and bitrate of the original audio file to use as parameters in loudnorm
  DO (  
      SET FFREPORT=file="C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Logs\!filename!.log":level=24 ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "!filename!.mp3" -af "loudnorm=linear=true:I=!-10.0!:LRA=11:tp=!-0.1!:measured_I=!II!:measured_LRA=!ILRA!:measured_tp=!ITP!:measured_thresh=!IT!:offset=!TO!:print_format=summary" -c:v copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" -acodec mp3 -b:a %%c -ar:a %%b "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs\!filename!.mp3"
     )
  ENDLOCAL
)

xcopy "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs\*.mp3" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Normalized µudios Lufs\LOUDNORM\MP3\LUFS %-10.0%" /y /s /i   ----> copying the audio files from the temporary folder to the final folder

                                                                __
del /q "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs\*.*"    |
rmdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Temp_normalizing_lufs" /s /q   |  Removing the temporary folder from the desktop
                                                                __|

Error log message:
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url file=ACDC - Jailbreak.mp3.log:level=24.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: file=ACDC - Jailbreak.mp3.log:level=24.
[NULL @ 0000021f879b8680] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'file=ACDC - Jailbreak.mp3.log:level=24'
file=ACDC - Jailbreak.mp3.log:level=24: Invalid argument
[AVIOContext @ 0000021f87967840] Statistics: 131072 bytes read, 0 seeks


Ps: Log files are generated in the original audio folder with the name ffmpeg-20240427-105701.log (without the audio name) and bat does not convert the audio.
How do I create log files, with the name of each audio, in another folder?
Баяр Гончикжапов
i insert your suggestion in my bat, but no works, see the change in my question.
Ps:
In my bat, the FFREPORT environment variable only works if I put SET before it.
I used command to change the log file path to another folder, shown in this link, but it did not work:
Creating a log file for my ffmpeg output
Command:
 SET FFREPORT=file="C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Logs\!filename!.log":level=24
Ps2:  the command is inside a DO loop, because bat will convert several audios in the folder.
Results:
the path does not work, the log file is generated in the same folder as the audio files, then it is automatically deleted and bat does not convert the audio files.

Option -report doesn't have argument. Try to set environment variable FFREPORT

@Баяр Гончикжапов
i insert your suggestion in my bat, but no works, see the change in my question.

Hmm, I did some research, it doesn't work on windows. So, you can try to redirect output: ...s\!filename!.mp3" -v 24 2>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Logs\!filename!.log"

@Баяр Гончикжапов, It worked, but the information that appeared on the screen no longer appears, what can I do besides generating the log file, the conversion information also appears on the screen?

As variant, you can cd "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Logs" then md "!filename!" then cd "!filename!" then run ffmpeg -report ... but level will be 48

@Баяр Гончикжапов, sorry, I didn't understand! where should I put the command cd "C:\Users%username%\Desktop\Logs" md "!filename!" and cd "!filename!" on my command line?

insert that lines after DO ( and before ffmpeg -report -i "!filename!.mp3" ... lines

@Баяр Гончикжапов It worked! Post your two solutions as an answer so I can evaluate it.

@Баяр Гончикжапов, When I ran it individually it worked, but when I ran it via bat, with two audios in the folder, it generates the log but doesn't find the file to normalize the audio! Report written to "ffmpeg-20240504-095623.log" Log level: 48 !Filename!.mp3: No such file or directory 

Sorry, I forgot. Add full path to audio ... -i "%Userprofile%\Desktop\µudios LUFS\!filename!.mp3" .... Because, bat file current dir changed to another folder, and can't find audio without full path.

and, maybe, you need to return to dir with audio

@Баяр Гончикжапов, It worked.. post it as an answer so I can select the best answer
